# Захват сообщений консоли

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Коротко: нужна функция, которая может слушать консоль и что-то делать с сообщениями оттуда.

А если издалека, то я обернул в electron чужой модуль, всё работает, но в течении суток иногда вылазит Uncaught Erorr (неуловимая ошибка) "потеряно соединение с сервером". По сути нужно просто попробовать ещё раз соединиться или увеличить таймаут, но там такое нагромождение файлов, что черт ногу сломит откуда эта ошибка лезет => Нужно перезапускать весь модуль. "try..catch" не катит ("[работает только в синхронном коде](https://learn.javascript.ru/exception#konstruktsiya-try-catch)"), window.onerror может быть, какие ещё есть варианты? как тупо повторять выполнение функции при ошибке?

Comment: по поводу "try..catch" - а вы создайте асинхронную функцию async function() {} и внутри нее асинхронные ошибки тоже будут отлавливаться (конечто, если разработчик модуля выбрасывает их наружу)

Comment: раз уж вы даете ссылку на learn.javascript, я тоже от вас отставать не буду: https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling

Answer (score 0):

По ходу от это мне бы тогда помогло 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever